# youtube live streaming PHP API integration

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have standalone web application which is based on PHP framework. I want to integrate Youtube live streaming into my application to enable live event creation and broadcasting. I don't understand the "register your application" part in integration (Please refer this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/). Can anybody help to understand this??

What is the best way to integrate Youtube live streaming PHP API into web application??

This is what I want to do though Youtube Live streaming PHP API:
 1. Authenticate youtube user account.
 2. Create a live event.
 3. define broadcast settings.
 4. Start live streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register means creating a projectId in cloud console: https://cloud.google.com/console#/flows/enableapi?apiid=youtube

Then you will use that credentials inside your project so that api server can identify your project.

Here's a live api php sample: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/create_broadcast.php

Comment: hello Ibrahim, Thank you for your quick help. Here is my query: 
How can I get the upload-video quality related details from Youtube?? Could you please redirect me to the relevant API's??

Comment: Thank you for the information Ibrahim. But could you please tell me how can I live stream  a video after creating the broadcast?